# indexer for Ethereum wallet-contract transactions history?

Tags: go-ethereum

I Would like to have my own server with a indexer for a ethereum full node using this repo https://github.com/Adamant-im/ETH-transactions-storage script, to have all wallet,contract balance and it's transactions, history I don't know if there a better and faster alternative or config to do that?

it's better have the indexer in the same server as the ethereum node, or use it as a separate each other?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best approach for having all transactions info it's to use etherscan.io api to have all data, without worrying about configuration,servers etc.